# Main effects in mixed ANOVA

Tags: anova

I am conducting statistical analysis of database. I have one within-subject factor (time) and one between-subject factor (gender). when I do simple within-subject analysis with only one factor (time), it shows significant main effect (p=0.027). However, when I add gender, as a between-subject factor, main effect of time changes and becomes non-significant (p=0.122). Please, can you help me interpret this? As I understand, main effect should not change by adding new factors in the analysis. which result should I report as effect of time on the dependent variable?

Comment: Your claim of `main effect should not change by adding new factors in the analysis` is false. What you just discovered is that after accounting for both time and gender, both variables become insignificant now. Basically a Simpson's paradox kind of scenario.

Comment: Thank you for your comment. As I understand, it such case interaction should be significant. in my case p=0.076 for interaction (time*gender). and please, can you advice which result should I report as effect of time on the dependent variable?

Comment: This is confusing, in your comment you mentioned interactions, while you did not mention any interactions in your question. Which is it? Can you post results from your model(s)?